# How to disable Ctl+c during OS boots up on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: grub2

When OS boots up, Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS .... connecting to cloud init.... during this phase when ctl+c is pressed it either halts the install or try restarting this phase again. Its required for me to disable ctl+c during this phase. Just need help how to disable during the OS on ubuntu 22.04 jammy.

Comment: Why? I don't think this is a good idea

Comment: What happens, is  our product do get deployed on ubuntu but during installation, our user pressed this interrupt key and installation halted, hence requested to disable this key.

Comment: @moo is possible disable during OS installation phase?